# Clear Browser's OLDER history only

Tags: google-chrome, history

Browser History clean-up tools work backwards.
I do not want to clean/clear/delete anything NEW, I want to delete the old stuff.

At my age. anything I did 10 days ago or more is already forgotten.

A couple tools and plugins come up from searching, but the links are long gone/dead/forgotten.

Windows 11. Google Chrome. All Microsoft updates installed.

Answer (score -1):

[Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/), a browser based on Chromium, has a built-in option for this.

In Preferences > Privacy and Security, there's a setting called `Save Browsing History`. The `One Week` or `One Month` options may fit your use case.

Other Chromium-based browsers (which would include Chrome) may also have this feature.

Comment: All Chromium based browsers offer this option

Comment: @Ramhound Good to know, Vivaldi was the only Chromium browser I had available to check.